# Picture are not beeing displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I made an instagram clone and I have a news feed where you should see the picture that the User has posted, but in my case the picture are not displayed.

I can't find any error don't know what I did wrong if I take a picture and upload it then the picture will be saved in the Firebase DB and will be displayed on my profile but not on the Feed.

This is the Profile.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

function Profile(props) {
  const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [following, setFollowing] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const { currentUser, posts } = props;
    console.log({ currentUser, posts });

    if (props.route.params.uid === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
      setUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);
      setUserPosts(posts);
    }else{
            firebase.firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(props.route.params.uid)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) =>{
                if(snapshot.exists){
                    setUser(snapshot.data())
                }else{
                    console.log('does not exist')
            }
        })
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection("posts")
        .doc(props.route.params.uid)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .orderBy("creation", "asc")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) =>{
            let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return{id, ...data}
      })
      setUserPosts(posts)
      })
    }
    if(props.following.indexOf(props.route.params.uid) > -1){
        setFollowing(true);
    }else{
        setFollowing(false)
    }
  },[props.route.params.uid, props.following]);


  const onFollow = () =>{
      firebase.firestore()
      .collection("following")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("userFollowing")
      .doc(props.route.params.uid)
      .set({})
  }

  const onUnFollow = () =>{
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection("following")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .collection("userFollowing")
    .doc(props.route.params.uid)
    .delete()
}

const onLogout = () =>{
    firebase.auth().signOut();
}



  if (user === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.containerInfo}>
        <Text> {user.name} </Text>
        <Text> {user.email} </Text>

        {props.route.params.uid !== firebase.auth().currentUser.uid ? (
          <View> 
              {following ? (
                <Button
                  title="Following"
                  onPress={() => onUnFollow()}
                />

               
              ) : 
              (
                <Button
                title="Follow"
                onPress={() => onFollow()}
              />
              )}
          </View>
        ) : <Button
        title="Logout"
        onPress={() => onLogout()}
      />}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          horizontal={false}
          data={userPosts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.containerImage}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerInfo: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  containerGallery: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerImage: {
    flex: 1 / 3,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  posts: store.userState.posts,
  following: store.userState.following
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

The Feed.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore'

function Feed(props) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let posts = [];
    if(props.usersLoaded == props.following?.length){
        for(let i = 0; i < props.following?.length; i++){
            const user = props.users.find(el => el.uid === props.following[i]);
            if(user != undefined){
                posts = [...posts, ...user.posts]
            }
        }
        posts.sort(function(x,y) {
            return x.creation - y.creation;
        })
        setPosts(posts)
    }
  },[props.usersLoaded]);

  
  return (
   
      <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={1}
          horizontal={false}
          data={posts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.containerImage}>
                <Text style={styles.container}>{item.user.name}</Text>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerInfo: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  containerGallery: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerImage: {
    flex: 1 / 3,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  },
});

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
  following: store.userState.following,
  users: store.usersState.users,
  usersLoaded: store.usersState.usersLoaded,

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Feed);
```

Comment: are you sure image url is changing ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure @Amruth

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the height , width without height width the react native app not showing the image or used the resizeMode.

resizeMode atribute (cover,contain,stretch,center)

<Image resizeMode="cover" style={{width:100,height:100}} source={{ uri: item.downloadURL }} />

Comment: Hello ! If I try this, I get a Firebase error

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of cached data, pass hash key along with image url so that your image loads on src change.

```
 <Image style={styles.image} key={item.downloadURL + `?${new Date()}`} source={{ uri: item.downloadURL + `?${new Date()}`  }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is under the hood, hopefully this is gonna work!

Whenever you use **aspectRatio** you have to also add **height: undefined** :

```
 image: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
    height: undefined,
  },
```

it won't work without it.